# JAVA - Run external jar file at start

Tags: java, class, load, runtime

I want to create an application that runs, and it has a folder which will contain jar files with minigames. I would like to create these minigames seperately as that will be easier to swap the games in and out. I just don't know how to load these jar files into my other already running application, so that I can just access the classes in the jar files and invoke the right methods with my annotations.

So, TL;DR, how do I add classes to my classpath on runtime?

With kind regards,
Stan

Comment: what is meant by `add classes on runtime` ? Doesn't get it what runtime behaviour you want in your application.

Comment: @Ankit I need to be able to add the jar files to the classpath when the main application first ran. So I can easily swap the 'minigames' (jar files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is probably not the best way to go, in my opinion.
With that said, here's an explanation that will help you achieve what you want:

Java works with `ClassLoader` which is a Java object that loads classes from a specific path, usually that would be the Java class_path. In order to dynamically load a jar, you can simply create a `URLClassLoader` with a `URL` referencing your jar, or alternatively add the jar `URL` to the current `ClassLoader` or to the system `ClassLoader`, depending on your use case. Once you loaded the jar, you'll be able to instantiate an instance of your Java class.
Following is an example of creating a new `Classloader` with a specific jar:

```
URL url = new File(jarPath).toURI().toURL();
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(url);
Object yourObject = Class.forName(className, true, classLoader).newInstance();
```

Of course, you should adapt the new instance creation to your class etc.

Comment: Would you mind sharing what you think is the best way to go? Thanks for the answer btw, works.

Comment: @Stannies this code is used when you need to dynamically load jars that are unknown at build time. If the jars are known in advance, just put them all in the class_path of your project and then you can reference their classes without the need to load the jars etc.